# My pivot table didn't respected the order of my groups

Tags: excel

I have 15 employees working on different projects right now. I took all the reception dates of the projects and checked the delay between todays date and the reception dates. it goes from 14 days to about 900 days. I created a pivot table, where I can see every employe and the delays of each projects in a horizontal bar table.

I Separated the groups like this : (0-60 days) (61-90) (91-150) (151-210) (211-365) (365+)

I used VLOOKUP for the groups.

The problem is, when I created my pivot table, the groups got all messed up and they are not in order anymore.

example : (0-60) (151-210) etc...

Any help is greatly appreciated

Here is a screenshot of my problem : https://pasteboard.co/IpNhm1c.png

Comment: Can you share an image? @MelanieDeschene

Comment: Well sure it did, it's following the order of the first 2 characters in the group name - `(0`, `(1`, `(2` etc. Excel doesn't *know* that 61-90 comes after 0-60, it's just working off the text you've given it. You'll have to manually adjust these each time you create a PivotTable.

Comment: @dwirony not sure I get it... Everything is in order, yet, it's not coming out in order.. here is an image : https://pasteboard.co/IpNhm1c.png

Comment: @siddharthasharma https://pasteboard.co/IpNhm1c.png

Comment: @MelanieDeschene That's not how pivot tables work - they will always sort into alphanumeric order by default. You can still drag the columns around to your liking, though.

Comment: @dwirony What do you mean drag the columns? Did you see the screenshot? https://pasteboard.co/IpNhm1c.png Not sure I can manualy drag something there... Thanks for helping!

Comment: @MelanieDeschene I saw the screenshot - yes, you can drag and move the columns, did you try? Left click and hold on 151-210 and drag it to the right, you can organize it however you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click the Column Header in the Pivot Table
2. While selected, you will see a thick border around the cell(s)
3. Click and hold the border and you will see a thick line similar to an I, this means you can drag this left or right and you can drop the header in whichever order you'd like. (I would start by moving the 366+ to the right side)